# Default implementation in protocol is not working for my case

Tags: ios, swift

I simulate my case in this example:

```
protocol MyProtocol {

    func doSomething()
}

extension MyProtocol {

    func doSomething() {
        print("Do something")
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {

    let button = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doSomething), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

I was expecting that `MyViewController` has already implemented `doSomething()` function, cause it was implemented in `MyProtocol` extension. Unfortunately I'm getting this error:

> error: argument of '#selector' refers to instance method
>   'doSomething()' that is not exposed to Objective-C

Am I able to fix or workaround this?

Comment: Please refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift-3

Comment: How it's related to question?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487168/non-objc-method-does-not-satisfy-optional-requirement-of-objc-protocol (possible duplicate?) you cannot define Objective-C compatible methods in protocol extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Your protocol is not Objective-C compatible. You need to annotate it with `@objc` or you won't be able to use the selector because the methods won't use Objective-C dispatch.

**EDIT**

So I should have tried it in a playground *before* writing the above.

You can't add an `@objc` function to a protocol extension in Swift. You'll have to put it in the class. or you can extend UIViewController to implement `MyProtocol`

e.g.

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol 
{
    @objc func doSomething();
} 

extension UIViewController: MyProtocol
{
    @objc func doSomething() { /* implementation */ }   
}
```

Comment: Did you try that? I wasn't able to make it compile, and according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487168/non-objc-method-does-not-satisfy-optional-requirement-of-objc-protocol it might be not possible. Seems like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @MartinR I've tried it now, and it's illegal to put an obj-c method in a protocol extension. The error message specifically says so.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem and solved it with a wrap object.

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {

    func doSomething()
}

extension MyProtocol {

    func doSomething() {
        print("Do something")
    }
}

final class ObjCMyProtocolWrap: NSObject, MyProtocol {

    // MARK: - init

    override init() {
        fatalError("Not supported!")
    }

    init(_ origin: MyProtocol) {
        self.origin = origin
    }

    // MARK: - protocol: Executable

    func doSomething() {
        origin.doSomething()
    }

    // MARK: - private

    private let origin: MyProtocol

}
```

Now you can use it like that:

```
let action: MyProtocol = OriginalObject()
let objcAction: MyProtocol = ObjCMyProtocolWrap(action)
button.addTarget(objcAction, action: #selector(ObjCMyProtocolWrap.doSomething), for: .touchUpInside)
```

But note: You have to store a reference to the wrap object (objcAction in this example)! The UIButton holds a weak reference only!